# Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid

Tags: reactjs

I understand it happens when two nodes  have the same data-id but how do I control that two nodes never have the same id? It keeps throwing this error all the time

```
 Uncaught Error: ReactMount: Two valid but unequal nodes with the same `data-reactid`: .c.2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.$/=10.0.0
        at invariant (invariant.js:39)
        at Object.getID (ReactMount.js:119)
        at findParent (ReactEventListener.js:39)
        at handleTopLevelWithoutPath (ReactEventListener.js:87)
        at handleTopLevelImpl (ReactEventListener.js:73)
        at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:136)
        at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
        at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:94)
        at dispatchEvent (ReactEventListener.js:204)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know which nodes those are, and those are some which are product of a map operation you can set a `key` such as `<Component key={index} />`.

Index of an item in array is usually used as a key if you do not have some unique key you could use.

Or if you are rendering the same component twice, then just set some provisional key.